# Certificate Request Info on a PKCS#10 to be signed

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509, asn.1, der

I'm doing a code that has to create a PKCS#10. To do that, I have to sign my "Certificate Request Info", but when I do, the application says that the signature is invalid.

I'm using the OpenSSL.exe to verify the P10, and the error was:
"ANS1_CHECK_TLEN: wrong tag". I think I'm signing what I shouldn't, so my question is, what's the exact format of "Certificate Request Info" that I have to sign?

I know that it must start with a sequence, but the p10 spec tells:

"The signature process consists of two steps:

1. The value of the certificationRequestInfo component is DER
   encoded, yielding an octet string.
2. The result of step 1 is signed with the certification request
   subject’s private key under the specified signature
   algorithm, yielding a bit string, the signature."

I'm not sure if the start must be a SEQUENCE (0x30 0x82 "the length>256"), or A OCTET STRING (0x04 0x82 "the length>256"), acording to ANS.1.

If someone please give me an answer like on this post, i could be the happiest man on the world. Thank very much:

[PKCS#10 request for a object key pair from PKCS#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967762/pkcs10-request-for-a-object-key-pair-from-pkcs11)

REgards, David M.

Answer (score 1):

The step #1 of the PKCS#10 standard talks about an octet string as the result of the `certificationRequestInfo` element encoding and does not refer to an ASN.1 type. The request signature is computed on this DER-encoding and therefore the *to-be-signed* object is an ASN.1 `SEQUENCE` and not an `OCTET STRING`.